# Initializing data in datatable from angular js controller

Tags: angularjs, datatable

I'm facing data initialization issue in Jquery datatable from Angular controller. Please find the approach below.
I've one angular controller as:

```
app.controller('CompanyController', ['$scope', 'CompanyService',function($scope, companyService) {
var self = this;      
self.companies=[];

self.fetchAllCompanies = function() {
  companyService.fetchAllCompanies().then(function(d) {           
       self.companies = d;              
       },
    function(errResponse) {
        console.error('Error while fetching Compnies');
    });
 };
//self.fetchAllCompanies();  
$scope.dataTableOpt = {            
      "aLengthMenu": [[10, 50, 100,-1], [10, 50, 100,'All']],
      "searching": true
};
}]);
```

HTML Code is:

```
<div class="row" ng-controller="CompanyController as ctrl">
<table id="company-details" class="table table-bordered table-striped" ui-jq="dataTable" ui-options="dataTableOpt">
<thead>
<tr>
  <th>Company Name</th>
  <th class="text-center">Created Date</th>
  <th class="text-center">Modified Date</th>                  
</tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
<tr data-ng-repeat="company in ctrl.companies">
  <td>{{company.companyName}}</td>
  <td class="text-center">{{company.createdDate | date:'MMM dd, yyyy'}}</td>
  <td class="text-center">{{company.modifiedDate | date:'MMM dd, yyyy'}}</td>                 
</tr>                
</tbody>
<tfoot>
<tr>
  <th>Company Name</th>
  <th class="text-center">Created Date</th>
  <th class="text-center">Modified Date</th>  
</tr>
</tfoot>
</table></div>
```

I'm using angular datatable and this is working as expected but there is one issue:
if I uncomment line `//self.fetchAllCompanies();`  from my controller then data table load data but while using some search of sort data is gone.
 But if I assign a hardcoded json to `self.companies=[];` in my controller then data table work all the way, now problem is that I'm initializing data by calling method `self.fetchAllCompanies()` it loads the data but other functionalities initialization gone.

Please help.
Thanks
Jitender

Answer (score 0):

I see jquery ui in your page. try to understand the behavior of jqui and deal with this code in a directive.

Comment: Hi, Thanks for your response, actually I think there is no problem with the jqui part as it is to add the features to datatable and that is working as expected, my main concern is I want to initialize the companies variable in my controller from service method that I'm not able to do outside a function e.g.  self.companies= angular.toJson(companyService.fetchAllCompanies()); something like that and that I'm not able to do at all, if I achieve this then it will be working, Service method fetchAllComapnies is not returning the actual response at this point of controller.